# pip install lxml on MacOS X gives error: command 'cc' failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

I'm trying to install lxml in my mac Mac OS X El Capitan. (V - 10.11.6).
However I do not want to install xcode in my mac.

When I try using the following command : 
pip install lxml

I get the error :  error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

How to install lxml in my mac without having to install xcode?

Comment: If the library consists of C files, you will need to compile these C files. I don't know of any pre-packaged python lib. Even if there are, I wouldn't trust them. Install a compiler!

Comment: Every search result suggests to install xcode for cc. How can I install cc compiler without xcode?

Comment: @Torxed: in general, there is such thing as binary wheels that contain precompiled C code (so user don't have to build anything). But for lxml only Windows and GNU/Linux binaries were uploaded (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.7.3), but not macOS. So, OP has to either find a wheel somewhere (which can be a bad idea, downloading random binaries), or install the compiler (not the whole XCode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to install cc without installing Xcode in mac.

See this documentation : https://hackercodex.com/guide/mac-development-configuration/

Also it is very easy to install Xcode in mac. Just download from app store, create an account if you don't have one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install XCode, just XCode tools. These guides should help you configure things:

- [Configuring macOS Sierra 10.12](https://hackercodex.com/guide/mac-development-configuration/) (see the *Compiler* section)
- [Python Development Environment on macOS Sierra and El Capitan](https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/)

Excerpt from the first article:

> Installing development-related software in the past has required the
>   compiler tool-chain that comes with Xcode. Thankfully, if you don’t
>   need or want Xcode, those compiler tools are now available separately,
>   saving download time and many gigabytes of disk space.